# Haskell function signature [[String], [String]] -> [String]

Tags: haskell

I have a function with a signature:

```
getPaperTitle :: [[String], [String]] -> [String]
getPaperTitle input = head input
```

I just need to get the first list of Strings but
Ghci is giving me an error:

```
Illegal type: '[[String], [String]]
Perhaps you intended to use -XDataKinds
```

Why is it giving me this error, and how can I fix it?

Comment: A tuple type is written `(a, b)` and not `a, b`: the parentheses are mandatory. The codomain of your function should be `[([String], [String])]`.

Comment: Domain, not codomain.

Comment: I'm not sure the body is right, either; what does a sample input to `getPaperTitle` look like?

Comment: Sample input would be paper = [["Computer Games as Motivation for Design Patterns"],["Design Patterns", "Games", "Pedagogy", "Java"]]. Chad's answer made it work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the body of `getPaperTitle`, the type signature should be:

```haskell
getPaperTitle :: [[String]] -> [String]
```

Type annotations involving lists don't need commas.